# XSS/SQLi/Javascript (Server-side & Client-side buffer overflows)

Tags: javascript, sql, xss, code-injection

XSS/SQLi/Javascript (Server-side & Client-side buffer overflows)

Very interested in:
XSS ~~> JavaScript ~~> Server-Side Buffer Overflow ~~> Remote Access
SQLi ~~> Server-Side Buffer Overflow ~~> Remote Access (haven't done research about sqlmap's skeleton & example that doesn't work 100% of the time, needs updating & fixing up)

Client-side buffer overflows are something I can easily do research on although most of the payloads are outdated by now but I think some of the outdated JS code can be fixed up a bit so that it works with the latest technology & security. Anybody have any great resources, articles, writings, or books detailing server-side buffer overflows from XSS & SQL injections?

I don't know Javascript yet but I plan on learning these languages thoroughly and carefully with the intent of having a bird's perspective: JS, C, asm, PHP, Python at the bear minimum... Any resources you can redirect a brother in?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what XSS, SQL injection, and a buffer overflow is?

Comment: XSS = cross-site scripting, SQL injection = database manipulation, buffer overflow = overflowing a certain part of a Stack for a app/service/kernel so one can inject their shellcode as long it is done correctly.... I didn't keep it clear enough, I am looking into ways for causing server-side buffer overflows via XSS javascript & SQL injection attacks which I know are possible..... It's very rare for someone to talk about it but it's possible... Take sqlmap for example, although outdated.... XSS on the other hand, was looking for XSS JS code injection ideas resulting in server-side bof's.... ;)

Comment: Sorry if you don't how to do it but looking for resources or books that cover the topics.... Think outside the box :P Don't be a square and realize that it's possible.... I've gotten confirmation from some blackhats that it is but originally my idea....  :P Not many people talk about it because only people who are creative & know how to code will be able to figure such a thing out :P

Comment: I just don’t see the causal chain between XSS and SQL injections on one hand and server side buffer overflows on the other hand. For example, how should a XSS, that happens on the client, should cause a buffer overflow on the server? Similar as for SQL injections: what server side buffer would you expect to overflow? One in the database engine? Or one in the application processing the data? Buffer overflows generally only happen in low level languages, which allow the direct access to memory like C. However, as for the other languages, memory management is handled by the language runtime.

Comment: http://bishankochher.blogspot.com/2011/12/nodejs-security-good-bad-and-ugly.html <~~~ this is just an example with server-side JS node.js.... and with SQLi, I have to do more research which is why I mentioned there is a function with sqlmap to cause a buffer overflow using specific queries once a solid URI has been found but hasn't worked any of the times I've attempted it because I think it's only a base skeleton & it isn't fully developed for obvious reasons.... Don't want to give too much power to the blackhats or leaving them to figure out methods & techniques on their own

Comment: If you evaluate user provided data as node.js code via `eval`, I’m not surprised you can make the program throw exceptions by providing invalid code. And if you don’t add exception handling, the program will consequently crash.

Comment: But the mentioned example is neither XSS, nor SQL injection now a buffer overflow. It’s just code injection. And the given example is an example by the book of things to avoid in your program: using `eval` on data manipulable by the user.

Comment: Awesome dude. Just what I wanted to experiment with. JS server-side code injection. I will have to do research as I am now only beginning to teach myself how to code & program.